How to move a lead to an specific stage?
I'm new on bitrix24,  I just started reading all the documentation about the API consumption and I want to start doing some things, starting by moving leads that haven't had any modification on the last 10 days to certain stages, but after reading a lot I cannot find any way that I could retrieve any Id related to the stage a lead is in on the crm.lead.list endpoint, I'm hitting my face to the wall trying to replicate this behaviour on triggers, but I think it is more painful.
I just consumed the crm.lead.list and check for any special IDS that correlate the stages categories, with no result, is it possible to move leads to other stages using a webhook with php?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I was trying to move leads that did not have any update or activity, I solved anything with the API using php, I needed the stage status, and I figure it out by using the status_id which is the id of the stages, I retrieved all the lead with the range of date using the modification date that were more than 10 days, then proceeded to move them to the correct stage.

You can try looping this code, it worked for me, you just need to make sure you get the stage id right. HTML elements with the class main-kanban-column-body have data-id attributes that store the stage's ID. I also recommend you to read this documentation
<?php

$webhookUrl = 'Your Webhook';


$leadId = 'xxx'; // Lead ID
$newStageId = 'xxxxx'; // Stage ID


function updateLeadStage($webhookUrl, $leadId, $newStageId) {
    $updateUrl = "$webhookUrl/crm.lead.update";
    $postData = http_build_query([
        'id' => $leadId,
        'fields' => [
            'STATUS_ID' => $newStageId
        ]
    ]);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $updateUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($response, true);
}

$result = updateLeadStage($webhookUrl, $leadId, $newStageId);

if ($result['result']) {
    echo "Lead stage successfully updated.";
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
?>

example stage id
